# How to invoke Queue Manager connection with different user?

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I'm executing a program that gets access to a MQ Queue Manager with java. The programs works, but when I run the .jar in a server, it cannot access the MQ. I asked the administrator, and it tells me that the .jar is running with the user `mqm`. There's another user that could run it. How can I run the jar so it runs under this other user? Or do I have to change something in my code?

Answer (score 4):

Setting a UserID in the channel's MCAUSER field means that EVERYBODY connecting on the channel will be using that particular UserID.

Its like going to a conference and everybody getting the same conference badge with the name of "Joe" written on it.  Not really useful or secure. Why both.

Answer (score 1):

How does the application connects to MQ? Does it run on the same server as WMQ and connects locally (in bindings mode)?  You can run the application as a non-mqm user and authorize that user to connect to WMQ queue manager and the relevant queue (put or get).
If its running on a different server, it has to connect through a server connection channel.  The easiest way is to set a user id (MCAUSER) on that channel and give connect permissions for that user/group on the queue manager and put/get permissions on the queue.

Comment: I connect using the Java Library to connect to MQ. I set the host, port, manager name, channel and queue to connect. When the programs tries to get an instance to the manager, it can't connect because the user by default seems to be mqm. It runs on a AIX server as a runnable jar and connects to another AIX server which has the QManager.

Comment: Ask your MQ administrator to set MCAUSER on the channel used by the application to connect to the queue manager.  It can be a non-mqm user, but should be a valid user and should have a valid group on the mq AIX machine.  This user should be given permissions (through setmqaut or AUTHREC) to connect to the queue manager and either put or get on the relevant queue.

Comment: According to the admin, there's no MCAUSERID in the channel. The admin insists that the user is set on my code. The only thing I do on code is call an instance of the Queue Manager, with an MQQueueManager constructor that sends the manager's name and a HashTable with 3 properties set: the channel, the host and the port. So I see no user here. Is there a way to set that with MQQueueManager?

Comment: MQ doesnt do any authentication. It just looks up the respective directory/file/service whether its a valid user and allows access based on the user's group profile authorizations (set via setmqaut or AUTHREC).  If MCAUSER is not set, the application's running user id will be presented to the queue manager. Always run it as a valid non-mqm user. The MQ administrator should setup permissions for that user otherwise the application will fail to connect.  You can also provide a alternate userid when constructing the MQQueueManager object. Check the MQ API docs before going this way.

Comment: Now that's weird, I execute my application as let's say `user1`, but according to the server logs I try to access via `mqm`. The admin says that the program is starting as `user1` but some part of the code is making the connection with `mqm`, which, I found weird.

Comment: Is the user1 available on MQ server? or does the user id of user1 maps to some other user on the mq server which is under mqm group?

Answer (score 0):

First, answering @nsupath last question, there seemed to be a problem. There was a user that was not supposed to have privileges. When first, updating the user registry and second, modifying the entire code (that hurt -_-) to make it accept user as an attribute, I finally managed to make it connect.

Though there was some problem maybe. Probably it didn't refresh the permissions, or something. The admin is as confused as me. Anyway, problem solved. Thanks =)